# Renewing expired UK driving licence aged over 70 years and resident outside the UK

Tags: driving-license, non-residents

My Uk old style paper driving licence has expired due to being over 70, and I now permanently live in South Africe. Can I renew my UK driving licence and change it to a new photo style at the same time?

Comment: The renewal page says you need to list your last addresses for the last 3 years. I assume they need to be UK ones. Are you able to do that? On another website, someone queried DVLA who said you must be resident in the UK to renew a drivers licence.

Comment: If you're permanently resident in ZA, shouldn't you be applying for a ZA drivers license (and possibly endure the 'dreaded' K53 like the locals do if your UK license isn't 'transferable')?

Comment: From the relevant page on the [gov.za](http://www.gov.za/services/driving-licence-driving/convert-foreign-driving-licence) web site: "If you have been granted South African permanent residence, you must convert your foreign driving licence to a South African one within a year of receiving your permanent residence permit.".

Comment: Would you guys be able to move these comments to an answer?

Answer (score 2):

No. You need to get a South African licence.

From [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/renew-driving-licence-at-70):

> You can use this service to renew your British driving licence if
>   you’re 70 or over, or will be 70 in the next 90 days, and:
>
> - your British licence has expired – or it’s going to expire within 90    days
> - you’re a resident of Great Britain

[And](https://www.gov.uk/change-address-driving-licence):

> **If you’re moving abroad**
>
> You can’t register your new address on your British driving licence.
>   Contact the driving licence authority in your new country of
>   residence.